# iOS Embedding Views

Tags: ios, view, controller, containers

I have an app where I using storyboards and I am wanting to have a view inside my main view and have it change between different views that are in my scene.

So at the moment I have "container object" which I can embed another viewController in, but I can't work out how to change that embed viewController when the user presses a button.

It's almost like I'm creating my own tabBarController I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You may want a view controller containment.

[Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW1)

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at this but I dont understand the implementation very well.

Comment: - (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
   [self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1
   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController]; // 2
   [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
}

Comment: Where does the method frameForContentController and property self.currentClientView come from?

Comment: -frameForContentController should be written by yourself. This method is to determine what is the frame of the child VC you want to add. self.currentClientView is an ivar of the containment controller, to know what is the selected VC.

Comment: @Oscar, can you clarify this statement:  "self.currentClientView is an ivar of the containment controller."  what is a 'containment controller'?  do you mean the controller that is containing or contained?  and if it is a "controller", why is it called a "view"?  can you give some example code?